# PDO ODBC not applying values to parameters in query

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, unixodbc

I am attempting to issue an SQL query that includes a parameterized value for a LIKE clause. Using PDO ODBC the query returns success and an empty result set. Using the odbc_*() functions I get the expected result set.

Queries without parameters work as expected.

This is going through unixODBC on an Ubuntu system

I would really rather use the PDO functions and take advantage of the OOP implementation, more modern fetch options, etc.

**Environment**:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- PHP 5.5.9
- unixODBC 2.2.14
- Connx 12

I have managed to create a very simple example that shows PDO ODBC apparently not using the parameters.

I have replaced my original example with this much shorter example.

```
// A value for the parameter
$desc = 'xyzzy';

//
// Using odbc_*( ) Functions with Connx
//
$db   = odbc_connect( ... );
$stmt = odbc_prepare( $db, "SELECT LENGTH( ? ) AS result" );
$sts  = odbc_execute( $stmt, [ $desc ] );
echo "Result using odbc_connect(): ", odbc_fetch_array( $stmt, 1 )['result'], PHP_EOL;    

//
// Using PDO:ODBC with Connx and positional parameter
//
$db   = new PDO( ... );
$stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT LENGTH( ? ) AS result" );
$stmt->execute( [ $desc ] );
echo 'Result using PDO:ODBC with Connx and positional parameter : ', $stmt->fetchColumn(), PHP_EOL;

//
// Using PDO:ODBC with Connx
//
$db   = new PDO( ... );
$stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT LENGTH( :desc ) AS result" );
$stmt->execute( [ ':desc' => $desc ] );
echo 'Result using PDO:ODBC with Connx and named parameter : ', $stmt->fetchColumn(), PHP_EOL;
```

Results:

```
Result using odbc_connect(): 5
Result using PDO:ODBC with Connx and positional parameter : 0
Result using PDO:ODBC with Connx and named parameter : 0
```

If you try this with PDO MySQL, you'll get a fatal error about an incorrect parameter count to native function LENGTH.

Is it possible this is a bug in PDO?

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I'd compare line by line the unixODBC traces obtained running the very same query with PDO (option 1) and odic_* (option 2). They cannot be the same...

Comment: I believe that this is a bug in PHP/PDO 5.5.9 under Ubuntu 14.04. I've upgraded to PHP 7 (planned to do that anyway), and this issue went away.